# Removing the space between cells of a grid

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to remove the spaces between the cells so that the grid looks kind of like graph paper. There is a small space between the cells right now and I would like to remove that that.

Here is that I have now:

```js
function generateGrid(rows, cols) {
  var grid = "<table>";
  for (row = 1; row <= rows; row++) {
    grid += "<tr>";
    for (col = 1; col <= cols; col++) {
      grid += "<td></td>";
    }
    grid += "</tr>";
  }
  return grid;
}

$("#tableContainer").append(generateGrid(5, 5));

$("td").click(function() {
  var index = $("td").index(this);
  var row = Math.floor((index) / 5) + 1;
  var col = (index % 5) + 1;
  $("span").text("That was row " + row + " and col " + col);
  $(this).css('background-color', 'red');
});
```

```css
td {
  border: 1px solid;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<span>Select a cell!</span>
<div id="tableContainer"></div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your CSS:

```
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
th, td {
    padding: 0;
}
```